# If two polynomials are equal, what can be said about their factorization?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, induction

I'm sorry if my question is unclear. What I am asking is, if you have two polynomials $f(x) = g(x)$, what can be said about the solution for $x$ for the equation $f(x) - g(x) = 0$? What can be said if $f(x) \ne  g(x)$ ?

It may help to clarify I am asking this because I am trying to write induction proofs, and maybe proving that $n = k + 1$ will be harder than proving that if $n - (k+1) = 0$ factors in a specific way, then it is equal/unequal.

I'm sorry if I put the induction proof equation thing wrong. I hope you know what I mean. If you don't, forget the second part... Im interested in the first part more.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x)=g(x)$, then $f(x)-g(x)=0$, i.e. the difference of the polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is zero. The degree of zero polynomial is defined to be negative infinity. When $f(x)=g(x)$, the solution for $x$ for the equation $f(x)−g(x)=0$ is *any* $x$.

If $f(x)\ne g(x)$, then $f(x)-g(x)=h(x)\ne0$, i.e. the difference of the polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is a nonzero polynomial $h(x)$. The degree of $h(x)$ does not exceed the larger of the degrees of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ (but may be smaller, specifically if $\deg f(x)=\deg g(x)$ and leading coefficients of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are equal).

Comment: Oh... that is so glaringly obvious... How would you prove that though?

Comment: By explicitly writing the expanded polynomials and using algebra; e.g. algebraic properties like this: if $r=s$ then $rx^n-sx^n=0$.

Comment: Take any factor of $g(x),$ say $q(x)$ it is plain to see that $q \mid g,$ and $q\mid 0,$ is certainly the case, so $q\mid f-g,$ since $f-g=0,$ so $q\mid f$ must be the case.